# Cannot upload image and not able to create password on Moodle for new user

Tags: php, mysql, php-7, moodle, moodle-mobile

I installed moodle 3.8 to my godaddy server, installation was successful, but I cannot create password for new user and also I am not able to upload profile image for a new user.

Please who has experienced this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it shows any errors or anything? please provide us with more information

Comment: No Error. Installation was successful. When admin is creating a user, I cannot put in the users' default password and the textbox is not coming up, also I am not able to create user.

Comment: Are you using `/user/editadvanced_form.php` ? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @RussellEngland Yes, the url is ```/user/editadvanced_form.php?id=-1```. The image has been updated above.